# Ajax post isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Quick question. I know this is a problem solved many times on stackoverflow, but if I try to make it work it no methodes work out for me. Am I doing it so bad? Here is my code:

```
$('.submit').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/clicky%20game/index.php',
        data:
        {
            userScore:score
        },
        succes: function(){
            alert('succes');
        }
    });
});
```

This piece of code is inside a script.js (linked to click.php) and it sould send the data to index.php. But it doesn't, I check this with the code (inside index.php):

```
if (isset($_POST['userScore'])){
       echo $_POST['userScore'];
   }
```

It just keeps showing nothing, hope someone can help me with this, thanks in advance!

Comment: Open developers console. What do you see there?

Comment: clicky%20game what is this ?

Comment: You misspelled `success` and also have no error handler and don't appear to be preventing default submit action

Comment: I don't see anything, no errors nothing :(

Comment: Where are you defining `score`?

Comment: Are you getting the 'Succes' alert? 'Success' will run if Ajax successfully connects to the URL and doesn't receive an error, regardless of the content. If you get the 'Success' alert, then there's a problem with your PHP receiving $_POST. If you don't receive the 'Success' alert, then there's a problem with Ajax connecting to the URL you've provided.

Comment: Well that solved my problem thanks! @charlietfl I feel a bit of shame XD

Comment: Add your html. If your `.submit` is a regular `submit` button you will need to prevent the default submittion of the form.

Comment: Oops a bit to quick I am getting the succes alert now but the index.php doesn't shows any value even if I replace the score with 1

Comment: @Dekel I changed to to type='button' so the page doesn't refresh

Comment: `type='button'` will cause your page to refresh

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Ajax works. $_POST is a PHP method that stores global variables from page to page. If you pass a javascript variable to a page then PHP will never see it. If this was possible to do then everyone would be hacked in a matter of seconds. You should look into REST APIs. That's what Ajax requests are for. HTTP POST and PHP POST are two very different things, but they do the exact same thing.

What you want to do is store a POST variable with PHP with a Form using the POST method. Then you can send that to index.php.

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<inputs></inputs>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok so here is why I used (atleast trying to use) my code. In the page jQuery has a variable score which has a value, so I started looking how I can pass that value to a php page

Comment: That's understandable. Unfortunately everyone is migrating to REST APIs and they are kind of hard to wrap your mind around at first. I know I had to read about them for months before I even had a clue. I would recommend learning NodeJS. It's pretty much the future of software. You can even make robots with JavaScript now. Cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a regular `button` to click, you will have to prevent the default submission of the form:

```
$('.submit').click(function(e){ // added the `e` for the `event`
    e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the default action of the submission of the form.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/clicky%20game/index.php',
        data:
        {
            userScore:score
        },
        succes: function(){
            alert('succes');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry didn't fix the problem

Comment: Still Getting the succes alert tho, but it stil doesn't display the value on the other page

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to get. You have `alert('success')`, so you get that alert. What is the problem?

Comment: That the other page, the index.php, doesn't show the value of userScore

Comment: How do you check if the value is there or not?

Comment: See my question, the bit with isset is de code I use to show the variable

Comment: But how do you access that page? You just open it in the browser? If the answer is "yes" - you will not see the value (because you don't post anything).

Comment: I open it via localhost in a new window and ti

Comment: So you don't "post" anything, you will not get this there :)

Comment: I open it via localhost in a new window and type the url (http://localhost/clicky%20game/index.php). And if I hit the submit button I refresh the index.php

Comment: If you post - you get the correct result. The problem is that when you enter the URL (copy&paste the URL into the browser) you don't `POST` and therefor you don't get the desired result.

Comment: Hmm so you are saying the code is fine, but I am doing something wrong in loading the page? And if so how sould I do it?

Comment: Do you understand the differences between `GET` request and `POST` request?

Comment: That they are the same only that POST doesn't show the information in the url bar